# Receive Image as multipart file to rest service

Tags: java, json, rest, resteasy, rest-client

I am exposing a restful webservice, where i want to accept image as multipart file in the **json body request** i dont find anywhere a sample json request so as to hit my rest service from a rest client.my rest service uses this field above the class declaration @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
can anyone please get me a sample json request

Comment: The @Consumes clause means that the service accepts either application/json or multipart/form-data. In case the client wants to send an image, it will choose multipart/form-data and it will not send a json request. So I think you should be looking for a multipart/form-data request instead of a json request.

Comment: Is there any way where i can accept both json request and multipart request in the same method of a rest service class ?should i write separate method for getting image

Comment: See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.12.Final/userguide/html/Multipart.html#multipartform_annotation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `multipart/form-data` is to send multiple parts in one request. The parts can have different media types. So you should not mix json and the image but add two parts:

```
POST /some-resource HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
Content-Type: application/json

{ "foo": "bar" }

--AaB03x--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

... content of image.jpg ...

--AaB03x--
```

With the RESTeasy client framework you would create this request like this:

```java
WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("some/url");
MultipartFormDataOutput formData = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<>();
json.put("foo", "bar");
formData.addFormData("json", json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/image"));
formData.addFormData("image", fis, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
Entity<MultipartFormDataOutput> entity = Entity.entity(formData, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
Response response = target.request().post(entity);
```

Which can be cosumed like this:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(MultipartFormDataInput input) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> json = input.getFormDataPart("json", new GenericType<Map<String, Object>>() {});
    InputStream image = input.getFormDataPart("image", new GenericType<InputStream>() {});
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..instead of this upload(MultipartFormDataInput input) ,i want to map the request to a pojo..like this upload(Mrequest mrequest)..will this be possible ? also i copied the code for creating the request(above) .MultipartFormDataOutput is unavailable..can u please send me a request so that i can fire the request from a rest client plugin of google chrome

Comment: You can use a `@MultipartForm` as already commented by peeskillet. MultipartFormDataOutput is included in [org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.jboss.resteasy%22%20AND%20a%3A%22resteasy-multipart-provider%22)

Comment: hi @lefloh,i changed the webrequest forming part by using ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build(); instead of WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("some/url"); I am able to hit the rest service. FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/root/Downloads/index.jpeg"));There is actually a real jpeg image at this location.But ath this line in rest service InputStream image = input.getFormDataPart("image", new GenericType<InputStream>() {}); i am getting null pointer exception...:(

Comment: Exception is "Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: application/octet-stream and class type org.jboss.resteasy.util.Base64$InputStream"

Comment: I think you have a wrong import in your resource class. Use `java.io.InputStream` instead of `org.jboss.resteasy.util.Base64.InputStream`

Comment: Thanks a lot lefloh.I am marking your answer as correct. :)